# How i can update or put a new object into array of object? For Beginners

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

Basically I have an array of objects, and I have created a new object that I want to examine, I have to see if the new object contains the same keys present in my array of objects, then see if it is a completely new object and then add it, or check if it already exists and if so update it, in this case if it is already present the request is to update only the 'ingredients' property

**to be clearer this is the request**
**Okay this is the request : write a function that, given a recipe, adds it to the list of recipes or modifies the ingredients if it already exists**.

I wanted to know if it is possible to do this using a type of map function, however I repeat I have just started and I get easily confused

my tutor told me that what I did is fine but it doesn't give me any results when I go to view the array of objects

```
var ricette = [
  {
    nome: "Carbonara",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "uovo", "sale"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Amatriciana",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "pecorino", "pomodoro"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cacio e Pepe",
    ingredienti: ["pepe", "pecorino"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cicoria",
    ingredienti: ["aglio", "peperoncino"],
    tipologia: "contorno",
  },
];

let oNuovo = {
  nome: "Tiramisu",
  ingredienti: ["uovo", "mascarpone", "savoiardo"],
  tipologia: "dolce",
};

function aggiungiRicetta(ricetta) {
  
  let cerca = (el) => ricetta.nome === el.nome;
  let trovato = ricette.findIndex(cerca); 
  if (trovato === -1) {
    ricette.push(ricetta);
  } else {
    ricette[trovato].ingredienti = ricetta.ingredienti;
    
  }
}

console.log(ricette)
```

Comment: you can use Map and set keys as hases of objects, eg.:

export function computeHash(incident: object): string {
  return crypto.createHash("sha1").update(safeStringify(incident)).digest("hex");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this approach. Use this only for learning purpose because you cannot modify or add new values in global object

```js
var ricette = [
  {
    nome: "Carbonara",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "uovo", "sale"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Amatriciana",
    ingredienti: ["guanciale", "pecorino", "pomodoro"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cacio e Pepe",
    ingredienti: ["pepe", "pecorino"],
    tipologia: "primo",
  },
  {
    nome: "Cicoria",
    ingredienti: ["aglio", "peperoncino"],
    tipologia: "contorno",
  },
];

let oNuovo = {
  nome: "Tiramisu",
  ingredienti: ["uovo", "mascarpone", "savoiardo"],
  tipologia: "dolce",
};

let existing = {
    nome: "Cicoria",
    ingredienti: ["aglio1", "peperoncino2"],
    tipologia: "contorno",
  };

function aggiungiRicetta(newReceipe) {
  let name = newReceipe.nome;
  let trovato = ricette.findIndex(rec=> rec.nome==name); 
  if(trovato === -1){
       ricette.push(newReceipe);
       return "New Receipe Added! "+name;
  }
  //Modify existing
  ricette[trovato].ingredienti = [...ricette[trovato].ingredienti,...newReceipe.ingredienti]
  return "Modified Successfully "+name 
}

console.log(aggiungiRicetta(oNuovo));

console.log(aggiungiRicetta(existing));

console.log(ricette);
```

Comment: thanks so much I forgot to call the function!